# Security Token Generation in Trusted Identity Provider for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, authentication, security-token-service, token

I am using Thinktecture Identity Provider for SharePoint 2013. I know that, for FBA, we can generate security token for user authentication using SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication. But how can we achieve it using a Trusted Identity Provider like Thinktecture. Can anyone please guide me?